# Panda returns zero entries though the entries are available on the dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have been working a dataset named InSDN, and preprocessing the dataset using panda. After loading the data I can not retrieve the DDoS entries though the records are available in the dataset and I am able to retrieve other attack entries like DoS.

```
#import the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('./InSDN_DatasetCSV/OVS.csv')
df['Label'].value_counts() 

#returns #returns DoS, DDoS, Probe, BFA, Web-Attack, BOTNET
df = df[df['Label'] == 'DoS']
df.shape #returs (52471, 84)

#for DDoS conditon
df = df[df['Label'] == 'DDoS']
df.shape #returs (0, 84), but as it is shown in the above code section it has 48413 entries.
```

Comment: please provide an example of the dataframe or the `ovs.csv` file. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the index of the `df` you will find that it's `'DDoS '` with an extra space.

```py
>>> df['Label'].value_counts().index
Index(['DoS', 'DDoS ', 'Probe', 'BFA', 'Web-Attack', 'BOTNET'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: how could you know this when the question does not contain either the dataframe or the csv file from which the dataframe was created ?

Comment: quick search brought up the [dataset source](https://aseados.ucd.ie/datasets/SDN/)